# If BindingGroup name of type equals someName, Do Work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to check if the binding group of a set of CheckBoxes is equal to the name of the binding group that I set the list of Checkboxes to.

Using a foreach loop, I can find the children in a named groupbox, "Accessories".

Inside the Accessories groupbox, I have a list of checkboxes belonging to 2 different BindingGroups.

For example, in xaml i have:

```
          <CheckBox Name="AccessoriesSpareBattery"
                      BindingGroup="523S"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                      Checked="AccessoriesSpareBattery_Checked">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Spare Battery"/>
            </CheckBox>
```

There are 5 total accessories that i have in the groupbox, each with the binding group set to either "5233" or "523S"

And in code:

```
    private void S5233_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var c in Accessories.Children.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            if (c.BindingGroup == "523S")
            {
                c.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This block of code will go through each checkbox in the accessories groupbox.  However, the if statement gives me the follow error when i try to build.

error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup' and 'string'

How do I reference the binding group of the checkboxes so that only those specific ones are altered?

Comment: please provide more explanation, i can't figure out what are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: I have a list of checkboxes in a groupbox named "Accessories"  However, the accessories are not available to both parent products.  So I'm trying to find a way to only enable the accessories available to a specific parent product. S5233 is one product and S523S is the other product.  I tried creating a binding group that i have set on the accessories so that when i go to loop through the boxes using the foreach loop i could use and if statement saying that if the checkbox binding group name is equal to some string, then enable the checkbox so that it can be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BindingGroup` property is of type [`System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinggroup.aspx). Checking the MSDN page, you should be able to query it's `Name` property:

```
private void S5233_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var c in Accessories.Children.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        if (c.BindingGroup.Name == "523S")
        {
            c.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i see.  Yea that works.  On the xaml side though, how do i set the binding group name? when i try to set the binding group, VS is telling me "The TypeConverter for "BindingGroup" does not support converting from a string.

Comment: @Chutes: Take a look at the code samples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bindinggroup.aspx. In short, you also need to set the `Name` attribute in XAML: `<BindingGroup Name="523S">...</BindingGroup>`